# Getting stake, farm and liquidity information from wallet

Tags: stake

Hello guys so I'm trying to build a dashboard for solana wallets
How can I get stake, farm and liquidity information from wallet connected?
For example I have 6LP Farms from raydium and some farm in Orca
How can I get them ?

Comment: The question is a little vague, but you can start by getting all of the token accounts for a wallet using `getTokenAccountsByOwner` https://docs.solana.com/api/http#gettokenaccountsbyowner